# Juju deploying charm produces "local error: record overflow"

Tags: juju

I am trying to install a charm and I get the following error

> ERROR cannot resolve charm URL "cs:juju-gui": cannot get
>   "/juju-gui/meta/any?include=id": Get
>   https://api.jujucharms.com/charmstore/v4/juju-gui/meta/any?include=id:
>   local error: record overflow

This problem occured several times but i tried dpkg-reconfigure juju without changing anything else and temporarily the problem was solved. But it then occured again and dpkg-reconfigure does not seem to solve the problem.

I tried to find logs etc in order to trace it but it seems that nothing is logged in /var/log/juju of each machine i have.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if I specify the ubuntu version in the command it works:

```
juju deploy cs:trusty/galera-cluster-1
```

Comment: Given this workaround works for you, this sounds like a bug in Juju to me. Please could you see if you can reproduce the failing behaviour on a fresh system (eg. a VM) and if so, file a bug against Juju? This will help the developers make Juju better. Thanks!

Comment: I had already reproduced the problem multiple times in testing environment using fresh VMs from scratch. So I will try to fill a bug for juju. Thanks.

Comment: If you omit the series when calling `juju deploy`, it queries the charm store to find out what series the charm is available for. This looks like it was a bug in the juju charm store API, throwing an error instead of returning a json result. I've tested it locally and it seems like the error has been fixed. Can you confirm that it's working (or not) for you now?